# SDKBOX 1.3: I was trying to integrate Facebook on android but the application crashes on launch with error “Unfortunately, libcocos2dx has stopped”

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to integrate Facebook on android via sdkbox-installer but when I run it on any android device via terminal (`cocos run -p android –android-studio`),the application crashes on launch with error:

> Unfortunately, libcocos2dx has stopped

What am I doing wrong?

Btw I followed [Facebook developers tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/).

```
cocos Version 3.8
XCode 6.2
SDKBOX 1.3 (latest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are on the `ndk-r10c`or higher.

Try to clean and rebuild your project using latest version of `sdkbox`. If you want to update your sdkbox, run this command - `sdkbox update`

Hope this helps.